# Send date with header data in curl

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to send request to rest API using curl as following :

```
   $headers = [

       'Content-Type:application/json',
       'tranDateTime:  $tranDateTime  ',
        'applicationID: 123456',
        'requestSignature: 12337777' 
        
        ];
```

I want to send the current date with along with header data. I defined a variable `$tranDateTime` that holds the current date and time but it appears as text as following

```
REQUEST HEADERS
[
    
x-forwarded-proto: "xxxxxxxxx" 
host: "eea0d7e6-e1b7-4031-9486-a126bc29ab5d.mock.pstmn.io"
x-real-ip: "xxxxxxxxx"
x-forwarded-for: "xxxxxxxxx"
x-request-start: "t=1653479444.950"
content-length: "150"
x-forwarded-port: "xxxxxxxxx"
x-amzn-trace-id: "Root=1-628e1814-4076172a36d527b30ae483c5"
accept: "*/*"
content-type: "application/json"
trandatetime: "$tranDateTime"   ---------------------------->>
applicationid: "123456"
 ]
```

How can I insert the value of the variable?

Comment: show us the code of what you've tried so far

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try

```
"tranDateTime:".$tranDateTime
```

instead of

```
'tranDateTime:  $tranDateTime  '
```